# How to refrence body in the __digest function in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I plan to add digest header to my "HTTP Header Manager" in JMeter.
I plan to use __digest function referenced in https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html.

An example is:

> ${__digest(MD5,${message-body},,,)}

How should I reference the messege body according to RFC3230?

Comment: what do you mean? message-body variable should hold the entire request body

Comment: I mean, you have to somehow assign body of the post request to this variable ${message-body}.
How to make this assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) instead of the `${message-body}` variable and retrieve the request body dynamically in the runtime.

The Groovy syntax to get the current request body:

```
${__groovy(ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue(),)}
```

Put together with the __digest() function:

```
${__digest(MD5,${__groovy(ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue(),)},,,)}
```

Demo:

[image]

In the above example:

- `ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html)
- `ctx.getCurrentSampler()` resolves into [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html)

See the JavaDoc for all available functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on various [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shortcuts available for [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

Comment: Do you know how to apply Base64 encoding on the digest?
When I use function __Base64Encode() I receive different value from my postman function CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify() ?